# Multiple Completion blocks

Tags: ios, swift, protocol-buffers, grpc

I was following this tutorial:

https://medium.com/swift2go/building-grpc-client-ios-swift-note-taking-app-6133c7d74644

But I dont understand this piece of code as it got multiple completion handlers and I dont understand how this code works (I know this is part of a singleton class but what this code is doing and what is "notes?.notes" ???:

```
func listNotes(completion: @escaping([Note]?, CallResult?) -> Void) {
    _ = try? client.list(Empty(), completion: { (notes, result) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(notes?.notes, result)
        }
    })
}
```

Im stuck at this point from 8 days straight so please help me :(

Answer (score 2):

listNotes(_:) has its own completion block named completion.

In the body of the listNotes(_:)'s completion, listNotes(_:) calls an asynchronous, throwing function on the client variable named list(_:, _:).

The function list(_:, _:) has its own completion block and passes two variables into it; notes and result.

When list(_:, _:)'s completion block executes, the first thing that happens is it creates a GCD block to execute listNotes(_:)'s completion on the main thread.

Then it passes two block variables from list(_:, _:)'s closure forward into listNotes(_:)'s closure; a property on the optional variable notes also named notes (should be refactored imo) and result.

One very important thing to note here is that because client.list(_:, _:) is a throwing function and the error is never caught, if that function does throw, listNotes(_:) will never execute its completion block. I generally consider this to be very bad practice since someone could depend on that function to execute its closure regardless of success. You're essentially setting yourself up to break a promise you made in the function signature.

Comment: Last paragraph is really important. I always make sure that completion handlers _will_ be called, no matter what happens. Anything else is a recipe for disaster.